# Visual basic console application

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I'm making a console app for Computer Science that displays a message if two numbers are the same, and a different message if they're different.

Here's my code so far:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
 Dim NumberOne As Integer
 Dim NumberTwo As Integer
 Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number and then press the enter key")
 NumberOne = Console.ReadLine
 Console.WriteLine("Now enter your second number and press the enter key")
 NumberTwo = Console.ReadLine
 If NumberOne = NumberTwo Then
 Console.WriteLine("You entered the same two numbers!")
 Console.ReadLine()
 End If
 If NumberOne <= NumberTwo Then
 Console.WriteLine("You entered two different numbers")
 Console.ReadLine()
 End If
 End Sub
End Module
```

This runs fine, but the problem is if you enter two numbers the same, it says you've entered the same numbers, but when you press enter, it displays the other message saying you've entered two different numbers.

Does anyone know how I can make it only do one or the other?

Thank you,

Jake

Comment: `If NumberOne <= NumberTwo Then`: The VB.NET 'not equal' operater is `<>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change your code:

```
 If NumberOne = NumberTwo Then
 Console.WriteLine("You entered the same two numbers!")
 Console.ReadLine()
 Else
 Console.WriteLine("You entered two different numbers")
 Console.ReadLine()
 End If
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant - that little Else statement has made it work! Thank you!

Comment: Vote up required 15 rep :( I marked it as the answer though :)

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your effort